# Как запустить приложение только для одной модели?

Tags: android

Сделал прогу, есть 2 layout, 
один стандартный
второй для планшета с разрешением 600*1024

как назвать папку layout чтобы она запустилась только под 600*1024?

Comment: layout-large-mdpi   (1024x600) от http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16706076/drawable-folder-for-different-resolution-and-application-icon-size  для ресурсов `res/values-sw600dp/dimens.xml      (600x1024)`

Comment: @Saidolim, а land не нужно дописывать? что - то типо layout-large-mdpi-land? чтобы в ландшафтном виде была

Comment: если нужно только Landscape тогда нужно. Если не важно альбомный или книжный. тогда не надо

Comment: @Saidolim, тоесть если я напишу layout-large-mdpi-land то при запуске на планшете 1024*600, будет только ландшафтный вид? если перевернуть ветикально, то все равно будет ландшафтный вид?

Comment: если layout-large-mdpi-land,  и если перевернуть ветикально он будет стандартный layout брать. Этот layout будет работать только если оазмер и положения подходять